# If Java's http proxy is down, it reverts to non-proxy

Tags: java, networking, javafx, javafx-2

This is really unexpected behavior. I'm writing a simple web browser using the JavaFX [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html). To make the web requests go through a local proxy, I wrote code similar to this:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

It appears to work fine if the proxy is running. However, if it isn't, Java silently reverts to not using a proxy at all! How can I force Java to fail if the proxy is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do this with a custom `ProxySelector` which only allows your proxy, and doesn't offer `Proxy.NO_PROXY` as an alternative:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class AlwaysProxySelector implements ProxySelector {
  private List<Proxy> proxies = Arrays.asList(new Proxy[] {
        new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080))
      });

  public List<Proxy> select(URI u) { return proxies; }
  public void connectFailed(URI u, SocketAddress a, IOException e) {}
}
```

You install this selector using `ProxySelector.setDefault(new AlwaysProxySelector());`

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try this when I get the chance today and report back.

Comment: Thank you! This method appears to correctly reject the connection when the proxy isn't running.

Answer (score 1):

Vasily, one of the WebView developers, provided some [sample code to track load operation status](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2342472) when working with a proxy.  Not sure if it will help, but you could take a look at it.

Vasily, also [notes](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2342472):

> At the moment, WebEngine provides no special support for proxy or, more generally, HTTP authentication, but relies on what the java.net.* stack offers in that area.

If you bundle your application using the [JavaFX packaging tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABFECGG):

> The main application JAR file will include a launcher program that
>   takes care of the bootstrap launch...
>   Setting the system proxy for your application

Also, make sure you are using a the latest version of JavaFX as earlier versions had bugs around some of the proxy handling.

There is a [guide to proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) and in it, it mentions that https has it's own proxy handler: (https.proxyHost and https.proxyPort), so that is also something to be aware of if your browser will be making https connections.